# How does a radiation meter equipped with a Geiger-Mueller Tube measure radiation dose?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering

The GM-tube typically operates in saturation and an incident particle will result in total discharge.  Therefore, as I understand, the height of generated pulse is independent on the energy of the incident particle.

According to my recherche there is some kind of energy compensation so that the responsivity is flattened for different energies, but, putting [these curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93M%C3%BCller_tube#Photon_energy_compensation) as an example, assuming same count rates, I would get the same radiation dose for 100keV and 1000keV, because there is no information about energy in the generated pulses.

So I wonder, how devices like [this](https://www.gammascout.com/) (only to put an example, no advertising) can display radiation dose rate in μSv/h.

Comment: wikipedia has a pretty good article on geiger counters...

Comment: Of course I also read Wikipedia, but the article doesn't answer my question.

Comment: sorry, no harm intended. -NN

Comment: The Wikipedia article does a pretty good job of explaining energy compensation. Lower-energy gammas are more likely to be counted, but the shielding is more likely to remove them. Higher-energy gammas are less likely to be counted, but more likely to go right through the shielding so they have a chance of being counted.

If your question is about converting counts to dose, or biological impact, that's more indirect.